# How to set composite type array containing JSONB elements with a literal value?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, unit-testing, plpgsql

I have this type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.user_type AS (
    text_1 VARCHAR(512),
    text_2 VARCHAR(1000),
    jsonb_1 JSONB,
    jsonb_2 JSONB
);
```

And need to know how to format a literal value to set an array of this type for a unit test. I keep getting malformed array literal errors when I try to set it.

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "{{"(text 1,text 2,{"key_1":"value_1"},{"key_2":"value_2"})"}"
  Detail: Unexpected array element.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 during statement block local variable initialization
```

with this snippet:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    user_type public.user_type[] = '{{"(text 1,text 2,{"key_1":"value_1"},{"key_2":"value_2"})"}';
BEGIN
END $$;
```

**How do I form a literal string to set this composite type?**

For other unit tests I can declare composite types *without JSONB elements* and set them with literal values. For example this works:

For this type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.user_type_2 AS (
    text_1 VARCHAR(512),
    text_2 VARCHAR(1000)
);
```

This snippet will return multiple rows:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    user_type_2 public.user_type_2[] = '{{"(string_1a,string_1b)"},{"(string_2a,string_2b)"}}';
BEGIN
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _results;
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _results AS  
     SELECT * FROM UNNEST(user_type_2) x (text_1, text_2);
END $$;

SELECT * FROM _results;
```

as I would expect

```
+-----------+-----------+
|  text_1   |  text_2   |
+-----------+-----------+
| string_1a | string_1b |
| string_2a | string_2b |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use several levels of escaping for that:

- The array element has to be surrounded by `"`, because it contains `,`, `{` and `}`.
- Each of the `"` inside the array element has to be escaped to `\"`.
- The JSON elements in the composite type have to be surrounded by `"` (now `\"`) because they contain `,`.
- The `"` for JSON strings have to be doubled to escape the `"` from the previous point, so they eventually become `\"\"`.

Your assignment could look like this:

```
user_type public.user_type[] := '{"(text 1,text 2,\"{\"\"key_1\"\": \"\"value_1\"\"}\",\"{\"\"key_2\"\": \"\"value_2\"\"}\")"}';
```

Yuck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the INSERT statement produces this error: "SQL Error [42809]: ERROR: "user_type" is a composite type"

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question. Answer fixed.

Comment: omg, super ugly and it works, sorry to even ask that from another human being.  Thanks so much Laurenz!